# Create Stack Instances Parameter Issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, aws-cloudformation, boto3, botocore

I'm creating stack instance, using python boto3 SDK. According to the  [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack_instances)  I should be able to use ParameterOverrides but I'm getting following error..

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ParameterOverrides", must be one of: StackSetName, Accounts, Regions, OperationPreferences, OperationId
```

Environment :

> **aws-cli/1.11.172 Python/2.7.14 botocore/1.7.30**

imports used

```
import boto3
import botocore
```

Following is the code

```
    try:
        stackset_instance_response = stackset_client.create_stack_instances(
            StackSetName=cloudtrail_stackset_name,
            Accounts=[
                account_id
            ],
            Regions=[
                stack_region
            ],
            OperationPreferences={
                'RegionOrder': [
                    stack_region
                ],
                'FailureToleranceCount': 0,
                'MaxConcurrentCount': 1
            },
            ParameterOverrides=[
                {
                    'ParameterKey': 'CloudtrailBucket',
                    'ParameterValue': 'test-bucket'
                },
                {
                    'ParameterKey': 'Environment',
                    'ParameterValue': 'SANDBOX'
                },
                {
                    'ParameterKey': 'IsCloudTrailEnabled',
                    'ParameterValue': 'NO'
                }                
            ]
        )
        print("Stackset create Response : " + str(stackset_instance_response))
        operation_id = stackset_instance_response['OperationId']
        print (operation_id)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        print("Stackset creation error : " + str(e))
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.8.0 is the first version of Botocore that has parameteroverrides defined.
https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1.8.0/botocore/data/cloudformation/2010-05-15/service-2.json#L1087-L1090

1.7.30 doesn't have that defined. https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1.7.30/botocore/data/cloudformation/2010-05-15/service-2.json